# jsTree show expand/collapse icon dynamically

Tags: jstree

I am using jsTree with "data" option where in I fetch the JSON data myself (instead of using jsTree's AJAX option) and then render the tree.

How do I show the expand/collapse icon programmatically? i.e. if I know the number of child nodes for a particular node, can I show the expand icon and then have an event attached to it so that I can lazy load the child nodes?

I tried setting li_attr["class"]="jstree-closed" but it ends up adding this class to the already present "jstree-leaf" class on the 'li' node and so the expand icon does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "children" attribute to true on the node where you wish to show the expand icon.

Example:

```
{
  text: "My node",
  children: true
}
```

Source: [Populating the tree using JSON](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

Comment: `children` is an array, not boolean.

Comment: @Cotur When using AJAX children should be omitted or set to true. Omitting means the node shouldn't have children at all, while setting it to true means the node have (or could have) children but you don't know about them since that would be discovered with an on-demand call once the user press the expand button.